# Поддомен на WordPress, а основной на Тильде. Как поменять их местами?

Tags: wordpress, tilda

Есть сайт с доменом soundproducer.club,который создан на Тильде. Также есть сайт с поддоменом shop.soundproducer.club, который создан на WordPress. Вопрос: как мне домен и поддомен поменять местами? Чтобы поддомен был на Тильде, а основной домен: soundproducer.club на WordPress.

Comment: Насколько я знаю на тильде нельзя использовать домены 3го уровня. Во всяком случае без привязки основного домена к ним. Лучше совсем отказаться от тильды и сделать всё на ВП, тогда всё возможно.

Comment: Хорошо. Допустим основной домен у меня также на вордпрессе, тогда как мне поменять домен и поддомен в таком случае ?

Comment: 1. Всё на сервере делается. 2 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress